# Inserting an image in a wordpress themes .css so it's responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, image, themes, responsive

I am trying to put a custom header on a wordpress theme. I have main.css and responsive.css open right now from the themes folder. I put the image in the images folder. Right now the banner/header is a solid color 2d2d2d, which I found this line on main.css

```
#main-menu {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 0;
}
```

My banner is rectangle, I use the same color (2d2d2d) to create a fade into a image I made. It needs to stay stuck to the right side and have the background color to be visible where the image ends if the window is opened full screen.

As far as I got, I written `background: url(../images/banner104.png) no-repeat bottom right;`
To insert *somewhere.* I can't figure out where exactly. I do know that on main.css this doesn't work

```
.main-menu ul li ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
    left: 1px;
    z-index: 9999999;
    min-width: 180px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    float: none;

    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: url(../images/banner104.png) no-repeat bottom right;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .02);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .02);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .02);
}
```

Here is my website if inspecting the homepage will give you some clue. www.nationalcomicsnetwork.net

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: What about now? What is not clear about where to put a line of code to insert a banner image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: your first code show **main-menu** as an elements id (note the `#`), and your second code as a class (note the `.`). Maybe that's the culprit?

How about putting the image directly on `#main-menu` like:

```
#main-menu {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 0;

    /* new */
    background-image: url("../images/banner104.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

I also wouldn't recommend your banner to be 1206x104px with a solid background-color as you did. When you already use a png-file, use a transparent background and only make it as wide as the fading-out should go. Otherwise you may have responsive issues (especially on smaller screens or browser-widths).

---

I split up the *background* attribute, because I don't know if you edit the main.css directly or add your custom css file. If you add your custom one you don't want to overwrite the default background-color by using the background shorthand and not supplying a color value.
If you edit the main.css directly you can use the shorthand, but need to add the color value like:

```
background: #2D2D2D url("../images/banner104.png") no-repeat bottom right;
background-size: contain;
```

Comment: That works. I do have responsive issues but i'll take your advice about changing the banner

Comment: Then you are free to mark my answer as accepted. If you need help with your responsive issues, I'd be glad to assist you.